# Creating a parser for sequence verification

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my problem. I have a device that can receive messages Q with parameters a b c (I will call them Qabc). The device should answer with some other messages with parameters (I will call them Axyz). In fact the device can answer in several ways depending on the message, it can answer with one or more messages in a sequence and the parameters in the answer are important. For information the answers are decoded and parameters can be extracted easily (this is already done).

I need to create a program where the user can specify in a file what message he wants to send and what would the answers needs to be in term of sequence and parameters in the sequence. Note that the answers are not always in the specific order. As example the device could answer Ax followed by Ay or the reverse way or just Axy. With the same example, the device could answer Ay only because the x parameter has not changed but the one of the Answer contains the current value of the x. But for some messages the sequence is important.

Therefore I need a string representation of sequences with some definition of messages and parameters to be verified, possibly combined with boolean operators and functions like ANY or ALL. I need to create an interpreter for those strings and some code to verify what they represent.

Would any of you have experience with that, would you have ideas on how to do it, do you have examples in mind or some already existing methods and format, some references? This will be done in Python 3.x

Best Regards.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser

Comment: Finally I used pyparsing